# Using Normal distribution instead of Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am new to Tensorflow and machine learning. I need to use the Normal distribution with variational autoencoder. I have searched for examples that are used Normal distribution with no luck. 
Can anyone provide an example of a Normal distribution of output values in the neural network?

```
  def make_decoder(code, data_shape):

  x = code
  x = tf.layers.dense(x, 200, tf.nn.relu)
  x = tf.layers.dense(x, 200, tf.nn.relu)
 logit = tf.layers.dense(x, np.prod(data_shape))
 logit = tf.reshape(logit, [-1] + data_shape)
 return tfd.Independent(tfd.Bernoulli(logit), 2)
```

Comment: Look into [`tf.distributions.Normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Normal)